# Unicorn: Single setting to disable unicorn synchronisation

Tags: unicorn

Is there a single Unicorn setting which can completely disable unicorn synchronisation for a Sitecore instance? At the moment if I want to turn off synchronisation, I just delete the App_Config\Include\Unicorn folder, but I would like an easier to restore option if possible!

Comment: you can rename files to .disabled if you want :D

Comment: @AndreyBobrov I just wanted to avoid having to rename 8 files and then un-rename them afterwards!

Comment: you can create a script for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to  make a **Unicorn** folder hidden. But you need to make sure that you don't have any other config patches in out of the **Unicorn** folder for `/sitecore/unicorn/` section or it's children.

Comment: How do you "disable" the file `Unicorn.config`?

Comment: Renaming `Unicorn.config` to `Unicorn.config.disabled` gave me an error on startup of the site/every page: `Could not find configuration node: /sitecore/unicorn/configurationProvider`

Answer (score 1):

On Sitecore 8.1 I had to disable (rename file to .disabled at the end) these 7 files to fully disable Unicorn and not get errors.

- Unicorn.AutoPublish.config.disabled
- Unicorn.config.disabled
- Unicorn.DataProvider.config.disabled
- Unicorn.Deployed.config.disabled
- Unicorn.Remote.config.disabled
- Unicorn.Tfs.config.disabled
- Unicorn.UI.config.disabled

Answer (score 1):

as some other answers explained, you could just disable the files. A more, in my opnion, convient solution is to use the rule based configuration that was introduced a few versions ago. It can be used as some kind of feature toggle, thorough information can be found [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/rule-based-configuration.html)

in the web.config, add an appsetting:

```
<add key="UnicornEnabled:define" value="Enabled" />
```

within the sitecore patch files for unicorn, register the feature toggle settings:

```
<configuration xmlns:UnicornEnabled="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/UnicornEnabled/">
```

ANd last, but not least, toggle the configuration settings which need to be enabled/disabled. If you'd like to enable/disable a complete patchfile, just configure the sitecore node as follows:

```
<sitecore UnicornEnabled:require="Enabled" .... />
```

at the moment that you'd want to disable unicorn, just flip the appsetting to something else, and your unicorn is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable unicorn by adding the `.disable` extension to all `.config` files within the `\App_Config\Include\Unicorn` directory.